# X3D in Powerpoint presentaions

Tags: html, powerpoint, x3d, x3dom

I have a CAD model that I has been exported to X3D and want to embed this object into a Powerpoint (2010) presentation.

I tried creating a HTML5 page with X3DOM and [LiveWeb](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm#.VVstWEa6SFU) to render it within Powerpoint. While I can get simple examples to work, I don't seem to get my model to render with IE, however it works fine with Chrome and Firefox.

Is there someway to embed the X3D directly into the ppt or using directly the HTML5 code?

Comment: it will probably never work in IE. Why not happy with Chrome/Firefox? There's no way to embed X3D in PPT as far as I know :)

Comment: The LiveWeb plugin or the VBA method of embedding a browser control into a PPT all use IE and the not the default system browser. 
Hence the need for IE.